# Custom cell without xib cell, Any other way to resuse the story board cells. Is this possible?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, reusability

As we know mostly we use to create a common custom cell in xib, is there any other possible way to reuse the cell from storyboard. Is that possible ?

Comment: You can create a custom cell completely programmatically. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: what could be the reason for not using an Xib cell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class of the cell you are reusing to a custom class you have made.  You still have to create a new file and class for the cell on the storyboard and drag over all of the outlets.  When you create a new file don't check the "Create Xib" option.  Then go to the storyboard and change the cell's class to that custom class you created. 
[image]

When you dequeue the cell be sure to cast it as the custom cell you made.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

Once you do that xCode should recognize all of the outlets you made.

Hopefully this helps!